# Why does the CardboardVR Lollygagger project crash when loading a scene on a Nexus 4?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, nexus-4

currently working my way through this Cardboard VR tutorial for Unity - https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/cardboard-unity#6

The Main Menu is now currently working in VR, but when I try to load the GameScene the application crashes to Nexus desktop.

Does anybody know why this might be happening? This happens whether I use Application.LoadLevel or SceneManager.LoadScene.

--Rev

In case this might help somebody diagnose the problem, here's the what the adb logcat spat out around the time of the crash. I'm having trouble parsing it, but maybe somebody can spot the problem!

```
D/Unity   ( 6716): [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
D/Unity   ( 6716): [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0 AFBT
D/Unity   ( 6716): ANativeWindow: (1280/768) RequestedResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (1280/768)
D/Unity   ( 6716): Renderer: Adreno (TM) 320
D/Unity   ( 6716): Vendor:   Qualcomm
D/Unity   ( 6716): Version:  OpenGL ES 3.0 V@104.0 AU@  (GIT@Id3510ff6dc)
D/Unity   ( 6716): GLES:     3
D/Unity   ( 6716):  GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_fr
amebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_textu
re GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high G
L_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_textur
e_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_arra
y_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_
rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT
D/Unity   ( 6716): _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_que
ry
D/Unity   ( 6716): OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics device
D/Unity   ( 6716): InitializeGfxDevice OK
D/Unity   ( 6716): Initialize engine version: 5.3.0f4 (2524e04062b4)
D/Unity   ( 6716): AudioManager: Selecting OpenSL output...
D/Unity   ( 6716): Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
D/Unity   ( 6716): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless
)
D/Unity   ( 6716): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 6716): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harm
less)
D/Unity   ( 6716): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 6716): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harml
ess)
D/Unity   ( 6716): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 6716): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message
is harmless)
D/Unity   ( 6716): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 6716): - Completed reload, in  0.211 seconds
D/Unity   ( 6716): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll (this message is harmless
)
D/Unity   ( 6716): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll (this message is harmless)
D/Unity   ( 6716): PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
D/Unity   ( 6716): Found 14 native sensors
D/Unity   ( 6716): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001190 / 0.00s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / InvenSense
D/Unity   ( 6716): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001190 / 0.00s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / InvenSense
D/Unity   ( 6716): Requested framebuffer: resolution[1280x768], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[on], samples[1]
D/Unity   ( 6716): Created framebuffer: resolution[1280x768], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[24/8], samples[0]
D/Unity   ( 6716): UnloadTime: 1.771000 ms
D/Unity   ( 6716): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001190 / 0.00s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / InvenSense
I/Unity   ( 6716): Creating Cardboard object
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity   ( 6716): Cardboard:get_SDK() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\Cardboard.cs:40)
I/Unity   ( 6716): CardboardEye:UpdateStereoValues() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:141)
I/Unity   ( 6716): CardboardEye:Start() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:96)
I/Unity   ( 6716):
I/Unity   ( 6716): (Filename: J Line: 0)
I/Unity   ( 6716):
I/Unity   ( 6716): Creating new default cardboard screen texture 1474x887.
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity   ( 6716): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity   ( 6716): BaseVRDevice:CreateStereoScreen() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\VRDevices\BaseVRDevice.cs:104)
I/Unity   ( 6716): Cardboard:get_StereoScreen() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\Cardboard.cs:323)
I/Unity   ( 6716): CardboardEye:UpdateStereoValues() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:173)
I/Unity   ( 6716): CardboardEye:Start() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:96)
I/Unity   ( 6716):
I/Unity   ( 6716): (Filename: J Line: 0)
I/Unity   ( 6716):
D/Unity   ( 6716): Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
D/Unity   ( 6716):   Thread -> id: b7e6ef38 -> priority: 1
D/Unity   ( 6716): Unloading 7 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
D/Unity   ( 6716): UnloadTime: 114.665001 ms
I/DEBUG   (  185): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  185): Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:5.1.1/LMY48T/2237560:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  185): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   (  185): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (  185): pid: 6716, tid: 6746, name: UnityMain  >>> com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest <<<
I/DEBUG   (  185): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x9dc2bff0
I/DEBUG   (  185):     r0 9dc2bff0  r1 9dc2c000  r2 fffffe8c  r3 9dc2c000
I/DEBUG   (  185):     r4 9dc2bff0  r5 00000001  r6 9dc2bffc  r7 af6a0000
I/DEBUG   (  185):     r8 9a5625d4  r9 00000000  sl 00000002  fp a33d871c
I/DEBUG   (  185):     ip afb3fed8  sp a33d86f0  lr afa60d7c  pc afa60cec  cpsr 80010010
I/DEBUG   (  185):
I/DEBUG   (  185): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #00 pc 002b2cec  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #01 pc 002b2d78  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so (GC_push_all_stack+72)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #02 pc 002bb9fc  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #03 pc 002bbacc  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #04 pc 002b7840  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #05 pc 002b4834  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #06 pc 002b1128  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #07 pc 002ab1fc  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #08 pc 002aace0  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #09 pc 002abaa4  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #10 pc 002abb44  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #11 pc 001396d8  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so (mono_gc_collect+40)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #12 pc 003aea64  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (CleanupAfterLoad()+92)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #13 pc 00402a04  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::PlayerLoadSceneFromThread()+340
)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #14 pc 004027b4  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::IntegrateMainThread()+184)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #15 pc 003ffed4  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadM
anager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int)+388)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #16 pc 004002ec  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete
()+72)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #17 pc 004003e8  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PreloadManager::UpdatePreloading()+164)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #18 pc 003a7500  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*)+664)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #19 pc 00513b2c  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+700)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #20 pc 005192c8  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+264)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #21 pc 0000dbe7  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2@base.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  185):
I/DEBUG   (  185): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
I/ActivityManager(  548): Process com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest (pid 6716) has died
W/ActivityManager(  548): Force removing ActivityRecord{3c1c96 u0 com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity t83}: app died, no sa
ved state
I/ActivityManager(  548): Config changes=480 {1.0 272mcc5mnc en_GB ?layoutDir sw384dp w384dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.11}
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
I/ActivityManager(  548): Start proc 7649:com.google.android.gm/u0a75 for service com.google.android.gm/.provider.MailSyncAdapterService
W/ActivityManager(  548): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gm/com.android.email.service.AttachmentService } U=0: not found
I/ActivityManager(  548): Start proc 7682:com.google.android.gm.exchange/u0a74 for service com.google.android.gm.exchange/com.android.exchange.service.EasServic
e
I/ActivityManager(  548): Killing 5763:com.google.android.videos/u0a81 (adj 15): empty #17
I/ActivityManager(  548): Killing 4610:com.android.defcontainer/u0a5 (adj 15): empty #17
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
W/PackageManager(  674): Failure retrieving resources for com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest: Resource ID #0x0
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
I/ActivityManager(  548): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.DIAL flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.google.android.dialer/.extensions.GoogleDialtactsActivity} from uid 10
022 on display 0
I/ActivityManager(  548): Start proc 7883:com.google.android.dialer/u0a10 for activity com.google.android.dialer/.extensions.GoogleDialtactsActivity
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
I/ActivityManager(  548): Config changes=480 {1.0 272mcc5mnc en_GB ?layoutDir sw384dp w598dp h359dp 320dpi nrml land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.12}
I/ActivityManager(  548): Displayed com.google.android.dialer/.extensions.GoogleDialtactsActivity: +1s28ms
I/ActivityManager(  548): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launch
er2.Launcher} from uid 1000 on display 0
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
I/ActivityManager(  548): Config changes=480 {1.0 272mcc5mnc en_GB ?layoutDir sw384dp w384dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.13}
I/ActivityManager(  548): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest
/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity bnds=[568,185][728,385] (has extras)} from uid 10014 on display 0
I/ActivityManager(  548): Start proc 8002:com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest/u0a122 for activity com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest/com.google.unity.GoogleUni
tyActivity
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
I/ActivityManager(  548): Config changes=480 {1.0 272mcc5mnc en_GB ?layoutDir sw384dp w598dp h359dp 320dpi nrml land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.14}
I/Unity   ( 8002): splash_mode = 0 (integer)
I/Unity   ( 8002): useObb = False (bool)
D/Unity   ( 8002): surfaces: attach glview
I/Unity   ( 8002): Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
I/Unity   ( 8002): onResume
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Attaching window :0xb73d3c20
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Attaching window :0xb73d3c20
I/Unity   ( 8002): windowFocusChanged: true
D/Unity   ( 8002): SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 4, Memory = 1835mb
D/Unity   ( 8002): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 15), 0 little (mask: 0)
I/ActivityManager(  548): Displayed com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity: +364ms
D/Unity   ( 8002): [SHA1] a0cfe2f5c6cecd88aae2aef0de87a209b8be7076   23066600 bytes ~ lib/armeabi-v7a/libunity.so
D/Unity   ( 8002): [SHA1] 06f01cc28b6f52e2af6894f366dfb8c9e63ee257      45104 bytes ~ lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
D/Unity   ( 8002): [SHA1] 0f1d3f9c24a6219cf7348bf8f8709ee70d89e7ff    3758496 bytes ~ lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono.so
D/Unity   ( 8002): [SHA1] 31e4496152a50bf44f354d4a8ae7f038caa4c577   26329820 bytes ~ lib/x86/libunity.so
D/Unity   ( 8002): [SHA1] 0f2623fd8777a09de55336c57066c5a0c3c29e5d      26776 bytes ~ lib/x86/libmain.so
D/Unity   ( 8002): [SHA1] 151e9995f77f3d5778d93697de3c8bab1204419d    3636444 bytes ~ lib/x86/libmono.so
D/Unity   ( 8002): Mono path[0] = '/data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed'
D/Unity   ( 8002): Mono config path = 'assets/bin/Data/Managed'
D/Unity   ( 8002): PlayerConnection initialized from /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
D/Unity   ( 8002): PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55438
D/Unity   ( 8002): PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest
D/Unity   ( 8002): Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.84 [Port] 55438 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 3257369354 [EditorId] 2106478937 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(LGE_Nexu
s_4@192.168.1.84) [Debug] 1" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
D/Unity   ( 8002): Waiting for connection from host on [192.168.1.84:55438]...
D/Unity   ( 8002): Timed out. Continuing without host connection.
D/Unity   ( 8002): Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56354
D/Unity   ( 8002): InitializeScriptEngine OK (af696ee0)
D/Unity   ( 8002): PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [192.168.1.84:55438]
D/Unity   ( 8002): PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Checking ES 3.1 support...
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] ES3.1 not supported
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Request: ES 3.1 RGB0 000 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGB0 000 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Found: ID[1] ES 3.0 RGB16 565 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Request: ES 3.1+AEP RGB0 000 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Request: ES 3.1 RGB0 000 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGB0 000 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Found: ID[1] ES 3.0 RGB16 565 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Request: ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
D/Unity   ( 8002): [EGL] Found: ID[5] ES 3.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0 AFBT
D/Unity   ( 8002): ANativeWindow: (1280/768) RequestedResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (1280/768)
D/Unity   ( 8002): Renderer: Adreno (TM) 320
D/Unity   ( 8002): Vendor:   Qualcomm
D/Unity   ( 8002): Version:  OpenGL ES 3.0 V@104.0 AU@  (GIT@Id3510ff6dc)
D/Unity   ( 8002): GLES:     3
D/Unity   ( 8002):  GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_fr
amebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_textu
re GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high G
L_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_textur
e_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_arra
y_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_
rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT
D/Unity   ( 8002): _texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_que
ry
D/Unity   ( 8002): OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics device
D/Unity   ( 8002): InitializeGfxDevice OK
D/Unity   ( 8002): Initialize engine version: 5.3.0f4 (2524e04062b4)
D/Unity   ( 8002): AudioManager: Selecting OpenSL output...
D/Unity   ( 8002): Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
D/Unity   ( 8002): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless
)
D/Unity   ( 8002): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 8002): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harm
less)
D/Unity   ( 8002): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 8002): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harml
ess)
D/Unity   ( 8002): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 8002): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message
is harmless)
D/Unity   ( 8002): Loading /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
D/Unity   ( 8002): - Completed reload, in  0.220 seconds
D/Unity   ( 8002): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll (this message is harmless
)
D/Unity   ( 8002): Platform assembly: /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll (this message is harmless)
D/Unity   ( 8002): PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
D/Unity   ( 8002): Found 14 native sensors
D/Unity   ( 8002): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001190 / 0.00s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / InvenSense
D/Unity   ( 8002): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001190 / 0.00s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / InvenSense
D/Unity   ( 8002): Requested framebuffer: resolution[1280x768], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[on], samples[1]
D/Unity   ( 8002): Created framebuffer: resolution[1280x768], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[24/8], samples[0]
D/Unity   ( 8002): UnloadTime: 1.495000 ms
D/Unity   ( 8002): Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.001190 / 0.00s ; LGE Accelerometer Sensor / InvenSense
I/Unity   ( 8002): Creating Cardboard object
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity   ( 8002): Cardboard:get_SDK() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\Cardboard.cs:40)
I/Unity   ( 8002): CardboardEye:UpdateStereoValues() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:141)
I/Unity   ( 8002): CardboardEye:Start() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:96)
I/Unity   ( 8002):
I/Unity   ( 8002): (Filename: J Line: 0)
I/Unity   ( 8002):
I/Unity   ( 8002): Creating new default cardboard screen texture 1474x887.
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity   ( 8002): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity   ( 8002): BaseVRDevice:CreateStereoScreen() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\VRDevices\BaseVRDevice.cs:104)
I/Unity   ( 8002): Cardboard:get_StereoScreen() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\Cardboard.cs:323)
I/Unity   ( 8002): CardboardEye:UpdateStereoValues() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:173)
I/Unity   ( 8002): CardboardEye:Start() (at J:\Unity\Tutorials\VeryBasicCardBoardTest03\Assets\Cardboard\Scripts\CardboardEye.cs:96)
I/Unity   ( 8002):
I/Unity   ( 8002): (Filename: J Line: 0)
I/Unity   ( 8002):
D/Unity   ( 8002): Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
D/Unity   ( 8002):   Thread -> id: b7e71550 -> priority: 1
D/Unity   ( 8002): Unloading 7 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
D/Unity   ( 8002): UnloadTime: 87.258003 ms
I/DEBUG   (  185): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  185): Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:5.1.1/LMY48T/2237560:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  185): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   (  185): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (  185): pid: 8002, tid: 8031, name: UnityMain  >>> com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest <<<
I/DEBUG   (  185): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x9dc2bff0
I/DEBUG   (  185):     r0 9dc2bff0  r1 9dc2c000  r2 fffffe8c  r3 9dc2c000
I/DEBUG   (  185):     r4 9dc2bff0  r5 00000001  r6 9dc2bffc  r7 af6a0000
I/DEBUG   (  185):     r8 9a5625d4  r9 00000000  sl 00000002  fp a33d871c
I/DEBUG   (  185):     ip afb3fed8  sp a33d86f0  lr afa60d7c  pc afa60cec  cpsr 80010010
I/DEBUG   (  185):
I/DEBUG   (  185): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #00 pc 002b2cec  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #01 pc 002b2d78  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so (GC_push_all_stack+72)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #02 pc 002bb9fc  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #03 pc 002bbacc  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #04 pc 002b7840  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #05 pc 002b4834  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #06 pc 002b1128  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #07 pc 002ab1fc  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #08 pc 002aace0  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #09 pc 002abaa4  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #10 pc 002abb44  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #11 pc 001396d8  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libmono.so (mono_gc_collect+40)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #12 pc 003aea64  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (CleanupAfterLoad()+92)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #13 pc 00402a04  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::PlayerLoadSceneFromThread()+340
)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #14 pc 004027b4  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::IntegrateMainThread()+184)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #15 pc 003ffed4  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadM
anager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int)+388)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #16 pc 004002ec  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete
()+72)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #17 pc 004003e8  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PreloadManager::UpdatePreloading()+164)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #18 pc 003a7500  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*)+664)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #19 pc 00513b2c  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+700)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #20 pc 005192c8  /data/app/com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2/lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+264)
I/DEBUG   (  185):     #21 pc 0000dbe7  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest-2@base.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  185):
I/DEBUG   (  185): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
I/ActivityManager(  548): Process com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest (pid 8002) has died
W/ActivityManager(  548): Force removing ActivityRecord{521dc07 u0 com.OgmaDigi.VeryBasicCardBoardTest/com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity t85}: app died, no s
aved state
I/ActivityManager(  548): Config changes=480 {1.0 272mcc5mnc en_GB ?layoutDir sw384dp w384dp h567dp 320dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.15}
V/ActivityManager(  548): Display changed displayId=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known crash in cardboard plugin that happens on LoadLevel, workaround is to remove the OnPause method from BaseCardboardDevice.cs

See more details here: https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/issues/126

Another suggested solution is to disable cardboard components before loading level, but it seems to be not effective.

Comment: This should be fixed in the v0.6 release of the Cardboard SDK.